# Connect Questions to Stackoverflow Account

Tags: support, stack-overflow, merge-accounts

I asked a question here without being logged in. How can I connect this Question with my account?

Answer (score 2):

Flag the question for moderation attention, explaining what happened, what you want done, and what account you want it linked to. I'd do this from the account you want the question linked to, to save them having to check that it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

Write to `team@stackoverflow.com`, they should be able to do it manually.